# Problem iterating through a struct and class to find the lowest priced item. My function did the opposite, it found the most expensive

Tags: c++, file, class, sorting, pointers

I am new to stack overflow so any tips on how to improve questions would be very much appreciated. I am working on a homework project. This function, using pointers should iterate through the all the cars and find the lowest price. However, I am getting the highest value of the input file data and simply switch the less than or greater than sign does not suffice. One prints the highest value the latter prints out a memory address any advice? Here is a chunk of the first portion of the input file data: (There are two other blocks just like it in the input file, so a total of three chunks).

```
Hertz 93619
2014 Toyota Tacoma 115.12 1
2012 Honda CRV 85.10 0
2015 Ford Fusion 90.89 0
2013 GMC Yukon 110.43 0
2009 Dodge Neon 45.25 1
```

```
void findCheapestRental(RentalAgency *agencies){
RentalCar * leastExpensive;
RentalAgency * agenciesPtr = agencies;
RentalCar * invPtr = agenciesPtr->inventory;
leastExpensive = invPtr;

for(int i = 0;i < 3; i++, agenciesPtr++){
 for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++, invPtr++){
     if(invPtr->getPrice() < leastExpensive->getPrice()){
         leastExpensive = invPtr;
     }
 }
}
cout << "The least expensive car is: " << leastExpensive->getMake() << " " << leastExpensive->getModel() << " $" << leastExpensive->getPrice() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our [intro section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.comhelp/mcve). While we wait for that, I notice that you never seem to redirect `invPtr` from one `RentalAgency` to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Your code most likely has undefined behavior. I think you need to initialize `invPtr` in every iteration of the outer `for` loop.

```
for(int i = 0;i < 3; i++, agenciesPtr++){

   // Need this line
   invPtr = agenciesPtr->inventory;

   for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++, invPtr++){
      if(invPtr->getPrice() < leastExpensive->getPrice()){
         leastExpensive = invPtr;
      }
   }
}
```